# How to enable changes on commit in eclipse using egit plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, egit

I'm new in git. I'm using git integration in eclipse (EGit plugin) like below:

Define shortcut
[image]

selecting project and use above shortcut and see

[image: commiting changes]

when I'm clicking on any listed file compare window appears:

[image]

On same scenario in SVN I was able to modify changes during compare on commit. I'm unable to do so in eclipse using EGit plugin.

1. Is it possible with EGit plugin?
2. Should I enable modify mode somewhere?

I'm using Eclipse Luna  :

**Version:** Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) 
**Build id:** 20150219-0600 
**More :** eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64

I'm using EGIT Plugin (3.4.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple: No

GIT is Distributed and SVN is Centralized.

Commit on GIT is different from the Commit on the SVN
GIT(or any DVCS) has two steps to update a Remote repository: Commit and Push
Commit on the GIT will only commit changes in your local. Push will update in your Remote

Lack of this in the SVN enables us to changes while we commit.

The shortcut has nothing to do with Enabling Changes on Commit in EGIT plugin.

Thanks